# TypeScript is compiling into this failing JS file when importing a module. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, module

I have a pretty basic TS file that looks like this

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

axios.get(url).then(res => {
  console.log(res.data);
});
```

That compiles into this (added some linebreaks for clarity)

```
"use strict";

exports.__esModule = true;

var axios_1 = require("axios");
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

axios_1["default"].get(url).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

When I try running it with `node` I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/programation/javascript/typescript_2/fetchjson/index.js:5:20)
```

True enough when I `console.log(axios_1)` it doesn't have any `"default"` key.

I thought the TS compiler would handle this basic stuff. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an old CommonJs-module version of 'axios', which has no `esModuleInterop` flag

Update your `axios` and try again

---

Or you may import it like

```
import * as axios from 'axios'
```

(axios page says default export is the same as the whole module)